# How to add a value in an array to the values before and after it

Tags: javascript, data-structures

I am trying to turn an array of numbers into  steps of the value of the Non-Zero integer element i.e

```
spread([0,0,n,0,0] returns => 
[0 + n-2, 0 + n-1, n, 0 + n -1, 0 + n - 2]

spread([0,0,0,n,0,2]) returns => 
[0+n-3, 0+n-2, 0+n-1, n ,(2-1)+(n-1) ,2 + n-2]

spread([0,0,0,4,0,0,0]) returns => [1,2,3,4,3,2,1]

spread([0,0,0,3,0,2,0]) returns => [0,1,2,3,3,3,1]

spread([3,0,0,0]) returns => [3,2,1,0]
```

etc.

I have tried the traditional for loop, i have tried forEach, even array.map but nothing works as expected

Here is what I tried but it doesn't work

```js
function pop(balloon) {
  let res = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < balloon.length; i++) {

    let n = balloon[i];
    let before = balloon[i - 1];
    let after = balloon[i + 1];

    if (n !== 0 && i < balloon.length - 1) {
      res.push(before + n - 1);
      res.push(n);
      res.push(after + n - 1);

    } else {
      res.push(n);
    }

  }
  return res;
}

const array1 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 3, 0]
const array2 = [0, 0, 2, 0, 0]

console.log(pop(array1)) // returns[0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 3, 0, 0, 2, 3, 2, 0]
// expected output => [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2]

console.log(pop(array2)) // returns[0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0]
// expected output => [0, 1, 2, 1, 0]
```

Comment: Hows spread([3,0,0,0]) returns => [3,2,1,0] are mirror?

Comment: Definitely need to explain what mirror means in more detail because it's not intuitive from what is shown

Comment: You had me until `spread([0,0,0,3,0,2,0]) returns => [0,1,2,3,3,3,1]` which doesn't follow the suggested pattern at all.

Comment: @DMishra it returns [3,2,1,0] because that'll be [n, 0 + n-1, 0 + n - 2, 0]. Last element is zero because at that point, n - 3 = 0

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans it is the same pattern, the zero before the 2 becomes 1 and since that zero is also after 3, 3 - 1 = 2 + 1 which was gotten from the 2 , that makes it 3. Also , the second index after 3 will be 3 - 2 = 1 + 2 that is already in that index, that makes it 3, and the 1 is gotten with the n - 1 formula i.e 2 -1 = 1

Comment: It is not the same pattern, because you don't _say_ what the pattern is in the presence of multiple seeds (after all, there is nothing in your post that suggests adding values? Using the min, max, or average is just as reasonable an assumption), so please update your post to explain what the resolution is between multiple seeds. Do not put that in a comment, put that in your post: people shouldn't need to read through a comment thread to get [the question's details](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reduce the array by using a copy of the array and go left and right with a recursive function which checks the value to spread and the index.

```js
function spread(array) {
    return array.reduce((r, v, i, a) => {
        const
            iter = (v, i, d) => {
                if (v < 1 || !(i in a)) return;
                r[i] += v;
                iter(v - 1, i + d, d);
            };
        iter(v - 1, i - 1, -1);
        iter(v - 1, i + 1, 1);
        return r;
    }, array.slice());
}

console.log(...spread([0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0])); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1]
console.log(...spread([0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 2, 0])); // [0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1]
console.log(...spread([3, 0, 0, 0]));          // [3, 2, 1, 0]
```

A different approach by moving arrays and adding them.

```js
function spread(array) {
    const dec = v => Math.max(v - 1, 0);

    var result = array.slice(),
        temp = array.slice(1).map(v => Math.max(v - 1, 0)),
        offset;
    
    while (temp.length) {
        temp.forEach((v, i) => result[i] += v);
        temp = temp.slice(1).map(dec);
    }

    temp = array.slice(0, -1).map(dec);
    while (temp.length) {
        offset = result.length - temp.length;
        temp.forEach((v, i) => result[i + offset] += v);
        temp = temp.slice(0, -1).map(dec);
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(...spread([0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0])); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1]
console.log(...spread([0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 2, 0])); // [0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1]
console.log(...spread([3, 0, 0, 0]));          // [3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Comment: But please can you clarify what the letter 'd' represents in your first approach

Comment: `d` is direction or delta, which has the value for adding to the index and has the value of `1` for going to end of the array or `-1` for going to the start of the array.

Answer (score 1):

In three steps:
1. Explode the input array in an array of arrays, every containing single non-zero value.
2. Process every of those trivial cases separately.
3. Reduce them back into a single array.

(Not the optimal solution for sure, performance-wise).

```
const explode = arr => {
   const len = arr.length;

   return arr.map((val, index) => new Array(len)
      .fill(0)
      .map((x, j) => index === j ? val : 0)
   );
}

const pop = arr => {
   const nonZeroIndex = arr.findIndex(x => !!x);
   const nonZeroValue = arr.find(x => !!x);

   return nonZeroIndex !== -1 ?
      arr.map((x, i) => Math.max(0, nonZeroValue - Math.abs(i - nonZeroIndex))) :
      arr;
}

const sum2Arrays = (arrA, arrB) => arrA.map((x, i) => x + arrB[i]);
const sumArrays = arrs => arrs.reduce(sum2Arrays, Array(arrs[0].length).fill(0));

const spread = (arr) => sumArrays(explode(arr).map(pop));

console.log(spread([0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 3, 0]));
```

Answer (score 1):

One fairly simple technique, if not the most efficient, is to create a square grid with a row for each value, either all zeros or descending from a single non-zero value as described and then simply add the columns.

Here is my version:

```js
const pop = arr => arr.map(
  (n, i) => n == 0 
    ? Array(arr.length).fill(0) 
    : arr.map((_, j) => Math.max(n - Math.abs(j - i), 0))
).reduce((as, bs) => as.map((a, i) => a + bs[i]))

console.log(...pop([0, 0, 2, 0, 0]))             //~> [0, 1, 2, 1, 0]
console.log(...pop([3, 0, 0, 0]))                //~> [3, 2, 1, 0]
console.log(...pop([0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 2, 0]))       //~> [0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1]
console.log(...pop([0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0]))       //~> [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1]
console.log(...pop([0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 3, 0])) //~> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2]
```

Note that the intermediate result (after the `map`, before the `reduce`) for that last one looks like this:

```
[
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 2],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
]
```

From there it's just a matter of adding the columns, a simple `reduce` call.

### Update

NinaScholz's comment made me rethink a bit, and I realized that it's just as easy to do an initial `reduce` rather than a `map` and only create the arrays that are necessary.  This change should be more efficient:

```js
const spread = arr => arr.reduce(
  (a, n, i) => n == 0 
    ? a 
    : a.concat([arr.map((_, j) => Math.max(n - Math.abs(j - i), 0))]),
  []
).reduce((as, bs) => as.map((a, i) => a + bs[i]))

console.log(...spread([0, 0, 2, 0, 0]))             //~> [0, 1, 2, 1, 0]
console.log(...spread([3, 0, 0, 0]))                //~> [3, 2, 1, 0]
console.log(...spread([0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 2, 0]))       //~> [0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1]
console.log(...spread([0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0]))       //~> [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1]
console.log(...spread([0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 3, 0])) //~> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2]
```

With this change, the intermediate result (between the two `reduce` calls now) would only consist of

```
[
  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 2],
]
```

### Update 2

Seeing this again, I realize that the last change didn't go far enough.  We can eliminate all the intermediate arrays except for one used as a `reduce` accumulator simply by adding to the current value as we go.

Here is what I hope is my final version:

```js
const spread = arr => arr.reduce(
  (a, n, i) => n == 0 
    ? a 
    : arr.map((_, j) => a[j] + Math.max(n - Math.abs(j - i), 0)),
  Array(arr.length).fill(0)
)


console.log(...spread([0, 0, 2, 0, 0]))             //~> [0, 1, 2, 1, 0]
console.log(...spread([3, 0, 0, 0]))                //~> [3, 2, 1, 0]
console.log(...spread([0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 2, 0]))       //~> [0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1]
console.log(...spread([0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0]))       //~> [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1]
console.log(...spread([0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 3, 0])) //~> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2
```

This has no intermediate data structures except for that accumulator.  It does only the arithmetic necessary.  AFAICT, this is as efficient as it can get, modulo working with `reduce` rather than a primitive `for`-loop.  I'd love to know if I'm missing something, though.

Comment: @NinaScholz: Yes. As I said, this is not the most efficient, either in time or space, but it's quite simple. More efficient would be to not build the arrays in the case of a zero, but this was quick and easy to write and to read.

Comment: @NinaScholz: Added a variant based on this comment.

Comment: Thank you for this, never thought about it this way

Comment: we should wait some more days ... :-)

Comment: @NinaScholz: I figure by early 2021 I should have this entirely figured out!  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Somehow "old-school", but seems to work:

```js
let spread = a => {

    let add = a.map(_ => 0);

    a.forEach((x, i) => {
        for (let c = 1; x > 1 && c < a.length; c++, x--) {
            add[i + c] += x - 1;
            add[i - c] += x - 1;
        }
    });

    return a.map((x, i) => x + add[i]);
};

//

console.log(spread([0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0]).join())
console.log(spread([0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 2, 0]).join())
console.log(spread([3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]).join())
```