# How can the popping of water balloons be modelled using an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

This question was part of a series of questions I saw for a coding challenge but I couldn't make sense of it.

Context: Once a water balloon pops, it soaks the area around it, such that the ground gets drier the further away you travel from the balloon. The effect of a water balloon popping can be modeled using an array.

Task: Create a function that takes an array which takes the pre-pop state and returns the state after the balloon is popped. The pre-pop state will contain at most a single balloon.

For example:

```
pop([0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0]) ➞ [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
pop([0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 2, 0]) ➞ [0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1]
pop([0, 0, 2, 0, 0]) ➞ [0, 1, 2, 1, 0]
pop([0]) ➞ [0]
```

The title of the question is Circular Primes but it didn't make sense to me how circular primes relates to ballon popping. Here goes the circular primes I know, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_prime. My question is:

- How does circular primes relate to the problem?
- I don't understand the sample and expected outcomes.

Comment: looks like this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55432554/1447675

Comment: @Nina Scholz thanks but does the question relate to circular primes?

Comment: i haven't clodes this question, but it has similarities with the given data. i agree, that the last part of the question is questionable. in my view, circular prime is not connected to popping balloons.

Comment: @Nina Scholz thanks for the response but please I don't quite get what you mean by 'clodes'. Can I get you on LinkedIn as Nina Scholz?

Comment: @Nina Scholz thanks for the response but please I don't quite get what you mean by 'clodes'. Can I get you on LinkedIn or any other platform as Nina Scholz?

Comment: sorry it should read as *closed*. no i have not a linkedin or other account.

Comment: @Nina Scholz thanks once more. I asked about the account because I want you to offer mentorship to me. I have observed you here on Stackoverflow and I believe I can learn a lot from you. Hope it won't be too much to ask for?

Comment: sorry, i can not help.